# Avoiding Defining a pure virtual function in c++ in immediate derived class?

Tags: c++, oop, visual-c++

Do we have to compulsorily define a pure virtual function in c++ in the immediate derived class ? Or can we just avoid it so that we can define it only in concrete classes ? How is this achieved ?

Comment: You could just try it...

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8931630/33732

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No one forces you to implement pure `virtual` functions, so you don't have to. Your class will just be abstract. In a derived class, just leave the declaration out or re-declare it as virtual pure.

```
struct Base
{
   virtual void foo() = 0;
};

//this is OK, X is abstract
struct X : Base
{
};

//this is also OK, redundant, and Y is abstract
struct Y : Base
{
   virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

Comment: In my interview today I was telling the same thing today and my interviewers were arguing against me that it is compulsory to define it in immediate derived class !!

Comment: Send "your interviewers" an email with this link.

Comment: @SRINI794 well then, you should be happy if you don't get the job. The best jobs are the ones where you can actually learn something from people than know more and can teach you. :)

Comment: Probably a miscommunication - you are required to if you want to have a concrete instantiable class.

Comment: @Chad Well then the result is still pending :( I might lose my offer if i send it :P

Comment: Or reinvent a new OO Language like c++ :P

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no requirement to ever define any pure virtual functions in the class until you begin to create actual *objects* of that class.

Abstract classes are intended to serve as bases for other classes. The abstract class hierarchy can be arbitrarily deep, meaning that you are not required to define pure virtual methods in the immediate descendant.

Answer (score 1):

If there's some virtual pure method not implemented then the derived class is abstract. You must implement the method in some derived class if you want to instantiate it.