# What are the risks of not implementing a virtual method of my parent class?

Tags: c++, oop

I am pretty new to both the OOP and the C++ language.
Recently I have been given the task of come up with an object oriented design -which I guess I have done quite ok so far considering my lack of knowledge on the subject. And since I want to keep performing either like I have done so far or better, I want to get my doubt cleared.

I made a design in which the base class offers two virtual functions. Some children implements both virtual functions of their parent, but some others implement only one.
Now, I know that it is not the best / clean design somebody can come up with, and that if I do not implement (in some children) one of these virtual methods I might get warnings from the compiler. I know I can implement the methods, and when they are not needed they could simply return an exception, or simply do nothing.

With all  that said, my doubt/question is: What is the actual risk of not implementing one of these virtual methods in the children? What happens on the object which does not have a virtual method's implementation of its parent? I am looking for a rather deep insight - I mean, I am looking for an understanding on a object's guts level so to say.

If an explanation is not possible to be given, any reference where to possible look at will be equally Welcomed and appreciated.

Cheers!

**EDIT**
Hi. Thanks everyone for your answers. My initial question -at least in my head- was not related to "Possible duplicate" suggested by Viktor Chvátal - but this question he pointed at, ALONG WITH all the other answers to my question clarified and dissipated my doubt. At the beginning, I though that if child does not implement the virtual method from parent, there would be some sort of "**hole**" there, where a method (or pointer to method, or whatever) should be. But then what would happen is that the child would be using the parent's implementation.
Thanks everyone and sorry for the fuss of asking something which is apparently already answered somewhere else. The thing is I should read more about how stuff works, before giving somebody else's comments as granted - wich is what took me to ask this question in the first place.
I'll try no to repeat this mistake in the future.

Comment: It is not mandatory to override a virtual defined inherited method, it depends on your needs.

Comment: can you show some code? What makes you think there is a risk involved when a derived does not implement a virtual method ?

Comment: if the derived class is fine with the method provided by the base there is no reason to override it, I am afraid there is no deeper insight to this than that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do ALL virtual functions need to be implemented in derived classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931612/do-all-virtual-functions-need-to-be-implemented-in-derived-classes)

Comment: Hi. Thanks everyone for your answers. My initial question -at least in my head- was not related to "Possible duplicate" suggested by Viktor Chvátal - but his question he pointed at ALONG WITH all the other answers to my questions clarified and dissipated my doubt.
At the beginning, I though that if child do not implement the virtual method form parent, there would be some sort of "hole" there, where a method (or pointer to method, or whatever) should be. But then what would happen is that the child would be using the parent's implementation.

Answer (score 3):

That is not the correct question to be asking. The correct question is if the child class only overrides one or two of the functions it is allowed to override then the question is "Should my child class be deriving from the parent class". For example of a bad inheritance is:

```
class shape
{
public:
   virtual void draw();
   virtual void print();
};

class log : public shape
{
public:
   void print() override;
};
```

This is a bad inheritance as the two both need a print method but a log class has nothing to do with drawing nor is it related to a shape. Is it dangerous not in the context of security but in the sense that anyone using your code will be extremely confused it is.

An example of a better inheritance would be:

```
class shape
{
public:
   virtual void draw() = 0;
};

class rectangle : public shape
{
   virtual void draw();
};
```

Here square inherits from shape as a rectangle is a shape and the inheritance enforces rectangle to define a draw method. With this inheritance it is very clear as to what is going on and there is no risk involved.

Comment: such shape-square examples are questionable. For example a `shape` can have a method to stretch in one dimension only, while if you do the same for a `square` it isnt a `square` anymore

Comment: I have adjusted it to a rectangle as this should fix the question-ability

Answer (score 1):

> Some children implements both virtual functions of their parent, but
>   some others implement only one

That is perfectly fine, and that's one of the reasons `virtual` methods differ from `abstract` ones, former being optional to be overridden in more specific types (child classes).

> I know I can implement the methods, and when they are not needed they
>   could simply return an exception, or simply do nothing

Throwing exception, say not implemeted or supported, is bad idea. If you knew the specific type would not support specific behavior, that behavior should not be part of base class itself. You should implement such behaviors (which are specific to some derived classes) using interfaces instead.

Comment: Using C# terminology and concepts for C++, that can be confusing. Consider changing them :)

Comment: I don't think question is language dependent although it's marked with `c++`. That's pure OOP question. I think your comment is pointing at `Interface` terminology I used in answer?!

Comment: Yes, and `abstract` functions, which are called pure virtual and do not use any extra keyword. But I see what you mean :P

Answer (score 0):

You might be confusing virtual methods with **pure** virtual methods.

A virtual method is just a regular method that children classes can override, which means "swap the default behavior for a custom one".
You declare them like this:

```
virtual ReturnType myVirtualMethod();
```

Pure virtual methods, on the other hand **require** you to implement them in the child class. They are used when no sensible default behavior can be written within the parent class. In case you don't implement them, the child class will fail to compile, which is good, because it prevents undefined behavior - in this case: what should run when NO method was provided? It is impossible for the compiler to decide.
They can be declared with this syntax:

```
virtual ReturnType myVirtualMethod() = 0; // notice the "= 0" at the end
```

So I think the question you should ask yourself is this one: "can I provide any default behavior that works in most cases for this method?" If not, you should consider making the method pure virtual, otherwise implement the default behavior in the parent class, and don't bother overriding that method in child classes that don't need it.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I do not know if that question goes deep enough. As you can define any class with pure virtual functions and the child class define them but this does not mean they should be defining them. For instance a parent shape class and child log class can both define a print method but they should not be in inheritance with each other.

Comment: True, although I find it a bit difficult to confuse the meaning of an interface with another one. Sure "print()" could mean two very different things depending on whether it comes from a shape object or a log object, but this is precisely the point: one belongs to a shape interface whereas the other to a logger. However, the OP being new to C++ seems to confuse regular virtual methods and pure virtual methods. This is how I understand his question anyway. Your point is perfectly valid, I simply think it's unlikely this is what the OP is asking about. But then again, maybe I'm wrong