# Calling base method however only second level base method exists

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Imagine a huge code base with many many inheritance. At some point a line comes in your way in the class you have to work with.

```
inherited::Load();
```

This is do what it says. It loads the base object into memory.
*inherited is a typedef for the base class.*
However the actual **parent class does not have a Load method**.

As a quick example:

```
class Base {
public:
  Base() {};
  void Load() {
    cout << "Base ok" << endl;
  }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived() {};
};

class MostDerived : public Derived {
public:
  MostDerived(){};
  void Load() {
    Derived::Load();
    cout << "Child ok"<< endl;
  }
};
```

Here, if we call `MostDerived.Load()` it will call its parent's Load method, but the Derived class doesn't have its own Load, only Base's Load method.

What is actually going on here? Why there is no compilation issue?
Is the Derived class copies all the method of the base, so it will have a Load method what is prints "Base ok"? Or does Derived simply calls forward the Base method?

I found a related question [Do ALL virtual functions need to be implemented in derived classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931612/do-all-virtual-functions-need-to-be-implemented-in-derived-classes) and the answer says

> It inherits the bar implementation from its ancestor class.

For me it still miss leading that **explicitly** calling the Derived::Load() method works. However, there is only a Base::Load() method exists.

Comment: `Derived` does have a `Load` method, the one inherited from `Base`

Comment: And remember that inheritance is an "is a" relationship. `MostDerived` *is a* `Derived`, and `Derived` *is a* `Base`, which also means that `MostDerived` *is a* Base`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yep, the init should be Load. Thanks for pointing it out - edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is actually going on here? Why there is no compilation issue? Is the Derived class copies all the method of the base, so it will have a Load method what is prints "Base ok"?

Yes. A derived class inherits all methods from the base class. (yes really all of them, whether it can access them depends on the access specified for the methods).

> For me it still miss leading that explicitly calling the Derived::Load() method works. However, there is only a Base::Load() method exists.

Sloppy speaking the `Derived::` only tells the compiler to look for names accesible from `Derived`. As `Derived` does inherit from `Base`, it does have a `Load` method.

Maybe your confusion can be cleared up a bit by noting that `Derived::Load` indeed does refer to `Base::Load`:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
struct Base {
    void Load() {}
};
struct Derived : Base {};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::is_same_v< decltype(&Derived::Load), void (Derived::*) ()>;
    std::cout << std::is_same_v< decltype(&Derived::Load), void (Base::*) ()>;
}
```

This prints `01`, because `Derived::Load` is indeed a method of `Base`.

I hope the example is not adding confusion ;). It uses `std::is_same` to see if two types are the same. `&Derived::Load` gives me a member function pointer to the `Load` method in `Derived` whose type I infer via `decltype`. I compare that once to pointer to method of `Derived` and then to pointer to method of `Base`. It turns out that `Derived::Load` is a method of `Base`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Now it's much cleaner. So the Derived:: only tells that it have to search for a Load method everywhere, where derived is accessible. Like Derived  definition and Base definition. And it finds the Base's method.

Comment: If I get this right, the first statement is false -> prints 0, since Derived::Load decltype is Base, what is not equal Derived. The second statement true, so it prints 0.